# SwingBuilder like GUI syntax for Java?

Tags: java, swing, swingbuilder

Is there a library that makes it possible to write Swing based GUIs similar to the manner done by [SwingBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Swing+Builder) in Groovy?

I am hoping to develop a Java GUI application without embedding Groovy or another complete programming language in Java, and I find the standard Java syntax rather tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went down this path at one point, then I found [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) - unless I'm using a split pane, I can generally lay out each of my views in a single panel, with a minimum of hassle.  There is a tad of a learning curve, but once you are over the hump, you can knock out a really nice looking GUI in almost no time.

The whole paradigm of nesting panels inside other panels isn't clean for a lot of designs - you wind up fighting the layout manager.

Comment: Kevin Day or anyone who has used MiGLayout, I am new to java GUI builders, a couple questions: (1) how would I install the MiGLayout? (2) MiGLayout looks like it can be used integrated with Swingbuilder utilizing the features of Swing but the layoug of MiGLayout. Could this be confirmed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such a library, though something similar would be possible (without named parameters, though, which reduces readability). Someone may have converted SwingBuilder to java.

[Looks like you can get java source for SwingBuilder at http://kickjava.com/src/groovy/swing/SwingBuilder.java.htm. I don't know how current that is]

About the closest you can come in plain java is to use the "double curly trick" (which isn't really a trick, just an anonymous inner class definition).

The SwingBuilder example on your referenced page:

```
new SwingBuilder().edt {
    frame(title:'Frame', size:[300,300], show: true) {
    borderLayout()
    textlabel = label(text:"Click the button!", constraints: BL.NORTH) 
    button(text:'Click Me',
           actionPerformed: {
               count++;
               textlabel.text = "Clicked  ${count} time(s).";
               println "clicked"},
               constraints:BL.SOUTH)
    }
}
```

could be written something like the following in Java

```
new JFrame() {{
    setTitle("Frame");
    setSize(300,300);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    textlabel = new JLabel("Click the button!");
    add(textlabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(new JButton("Click Me") {{
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                count++;
                textlabel.setText("Clicked " + count + " time(s).");
                System.out.println("clicked");
        }});
    }}, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setVisible(true);
}};
```

NOTE: The problem here is that when you use

```
new SomeClass() {{ ... }}
```

it's actually creating a new class definition. I wouldn't recommend doing it very often because of this.